# How would I go about adding Tkinter to this program?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import sys
import time
from random import randint

replies =["It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Without a doubt", "Yes definitely", "You may rely on it", "As I see it, yes", "Most likely", "Outlook good", "Yes", "Signs point to yes", "Reply hazy try again", "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now", "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again", "Don't count on it", "My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not so good", "Very doubtful"]

def question():
        print "What is your question?"
        question = raw_input()
        print "Thinking"
        time.sleep(3)
        print replies[randint(0,19)]
        end()

def end():
        print "Thanks for playing! Do you want to try again?"
        user_reply = raw_input()
        if user_reply == "Yes" or "yes":
                question()
        else user_reply == "No" or "no":
            print "Goodbye!"
            sys.exit

print 
print "**********Welcome to the Magic 8-ball!**********"
print
question()
```

It's fine as it is, but I'd like to do something a bit more challenging. I'd like to add a GUI(Tkinter) to make it a bit more interesting. Where should I start?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question mate. You should start buy reading the tkinter documentation or a tutorial.

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with Tkinter, but the one program I've made with it, I started from scratch. I was wondering how hard it'd be to incorporate it into what I already have.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the best solution would be to rewrite your program from scratch. GUI programs don't work top-down like your program, and GUI programs shouldn't call `sleep`. You need to rethink how the program should work from an event-driven perspective.

Comment: In this specific case, the best course of action would have been to write a comment instead of an answer, and vote to close the question.